# How can I save memory load and prevent a ZEND HEAP php error querying millions of records creating a .txt file

Tags: php, mysql, memory

PHP chokes up after about 45 minutes of processing records with a ZEND HEAP error which I spent countless hours researching and trying to resolve and was unable to do so. There is not an .ini configuration that resolves this as I researched and tried everything! It solely appears to be a php 5xx limitation or bug.

I have 6 tables and over 54,000,000 records I am querying. From these queries I generate a proprietary text file.

I am looking for the best recommendations in my below script or recreation of the script as I've modified it 100x times over the past year and it's gotten faster but I cannot get away from the ZEND HEAD error which kills my script on very large record sets.

This is not web based script all work is localized and run through the php cli.

**I should also note I spent countless hours re configuring php.ini memory settings and any other possible tweak I could try with no luck.**

I am hoping the script can be written in an OOP structure that allows much more memory efficiency.

Thanks in advance for any times or ideas. Below is my existing code:

```
<?php
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', '9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999');
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', '9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999');
ini_set('memory_limit','9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999M');
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server.
$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$connection) 
{
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Sets the active MySQL database.
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("charities", $connection);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
   die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Basic settings
$txtdate = date('Ymdhis');
// Filter only
$_POST["state_abbr"] = 'NY'; // State 
$_POST["loc_type"] = 'Non Profit'; // Church, School, Non Profit etc...
// Query parameters - eg for Open or Closed Status.
$_POST["case_disp"] = 'C';
$_POST["case_disp_txt"] = 'CLOSED';
$_POST["case_disp_gp"] = 'CLOSED';
$_POST["last_act_txt"] = 'CLOSED'; 
// Text output only.
$_POST["status_word"] = 'Closed'; // Location status: "ABANDONED" or "ACTIVE"
$_POST["stateU"] = 'New York'; 

$Locations_yr = "2012-" . date('Y');

// Selects all the rows in the markers table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM charity_full_merged as a 
INNER JOIN charity_full_merged_st_load_case as b
ON a.charity_id=b.charity_id
INNER JOIN charity_full_merged_land as c
ON b.charity_id=c.charity_id
INNER JOIN charity_full_merged_county as d
ON c.charity_id=d.charity_id
INNER JOIN charity_full_merged_customer as e
ON d.charity_id=e.charity_id 
WHERE
a.township_range_quarters != ''
AND 
b.geo_state = '".$_POST["state_abbr"]."' 
AND
b.casetype_txt LIKE \"%".$_POST["loc_type"]."%\"    
AND 
b.case_disp_txt = '".$_POST["case_disp_txt"]."' GROUP BY b.charity_nm;";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
$results_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

 $result = mysql_query($query);
     if (!$result) 
 {
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
 }
// Creates an array of strings to hold the lines of the txt file.
$txt = array('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
$txt[] = "<Document>
<name>" . date('Y') . " Data Map of " . $_POST["stateU"] . ". " . $_POST["status_word"]   . " " . $_POST["loc_type"] . " Locations. </name>
<description>" . $_POST["stateU"] . " " . $_POST["status_word"]  . " " .    $_POST["loc_type"] . " " . " map." .  " " . $results_count . " Records. Created by Charity    Group 5." . date('Y') . ". </description>";
while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        if ($row['last_action_txt'] == 'NOP' 

        {
            $boxclr = 'activeLoc';
        }
        else if ($row['case_disp'] == 'C' 

    {
            $boxclr = 'closedLoc';
        }
    else { // Unknown
        $boxclr = "yellowBox";
}
  $txt[] = "... general content written here ... (about 100 lines of text per  record ";
} 
// End XML file
$txt[] = ' </Document>';
$txt[] = '</txt>';
$txtOutput = join("\n", $txt);

// Create .txt file.
$txtfile =  $_POST["stateU"] . "Charities" . $_POST["status_word"] . "-" .     $_POST["loc_type"] . "-LocationS-" . $results_count . "-" . $txtdate . ".txt";

// Put the contents of $txtOutput into the $txtfile.
file_put_contents($txtfile, $txtOutput);

echo "$results_count " . $_POST["status_word"] . " " . $_POST["loc_type"] . " Location     records processed...";
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what error you are getting exactly?

Comment: One thing that stands out is that you're not writing out every line as it occurs, but storing it in a giant array instead. Use `fwrite()` to write out each line straight away.

Comment: Your script is crashing the PHP interpreter, there's no setting that will change that, and I'd be surprised if OOP uses less memory than procedural code.

Comment: I doubt you can go over max int like you did with those crazy `ini_set`s. Looks more like some terrible monkey patch than a solution.

Comment: Also your code is full of sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Also you are suppression errors rather than handling them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you already understand the general problem. You're trying to accumulate the entire result set into the `$txt` array - that's not going to work for huge data sets, as you're seeing.  Instead, you should allow PHP to output the data as it is generated.

So instead of:

```
$txt[] = "(header stuff)";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {  // Remove the @ here!!!
   $txt[] = "(content stuff)";              // This becomes 'huge'
}
$txt[] = "(footer stuff)";

$txtOutput = join("\n", $txt);              // Now your memory usage is
                                            // ~ 2 * 'huge'

file_put_contents($filename, $txtOutput);
```

You should [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) the file ahead of time, and [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) what you need as you go.

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

fwrite($fp, "(header stuff)");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
   fwrite($fp, "(content stuff)");
}

fwrite($fp, "(footer stuff)");

fclose($fp);
```

Additionally, when you have to try and use numbers like `9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`
for a socket timeout or a memory limit, that should be a big warning that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Last but not least, creating XML with `echo '<foo>' . $unescaped_random_input . '</foo>';` will fail sooner or later.

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart, It's been over 4 months of redeveloping and revising my script and now it was this simple all along!! Glad there are people like you that know a lot more than me!! I do a lot of volunteer work and this really helps a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: unfortunately the `mysql` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, but as long as it can be used, I would do a `mysql_unbuffered_query()` instead of a `mysql_query()`, for such a big resultset

Comment: @WalterTross Good point. Also, this means the OP should heed the warnings all over the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), and switch to MySQLi or PDO.